# Using Sample Dataframe to Create Artificial Dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have facing challenge while generating Data from Sample while inheriting actual properties.

I have a small sample of Data Set. The data set contains Numeric,Character and Alphanumeric values spread over multiple variables.For univariate data (numeric), I am able to generate huge volumes of data by using KDE. Curve of sample data and generated data is  similar in nature, thus holding back original property of the sample data. Now, I have the below open points for which I need some guidance.

1. How to Generate Data from Sample data for Character & Alphanumeric variables.
2. How to make sure that correlation between the variables of sample dataframe holds good for correlation between the generated dataframe.

I want an artificial dataframe generated which will hold all properties of sample dataframe......

Comment: Hi, I think it is not clear what you're asking. Try to get more concrete. Can you provide and example? Also, KDE=kernel density estimation or what?

Comment: yes....KDE is for Kernal Density Estimation....to be more concrete:
1. I am able to generate data for numeric variable using KDE...for how to generate data for character and alphanumeric variables?
2. How to maintain the same correlation of data when compared to with sample dataset to generated dataset.